# Insomnia : Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, insomnia

I added my own certificate to a node.js express server for testing purposes. Then I attempted to contact the post from Insomnia, but I received an error message.

`Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`

The server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
var https = require('https');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
const app = express()
const port = 8000
// app.use(express.urlencoded()); 
app.use(express.json());
// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'));
})
 
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.username);
  methods.signin();
  res.end();
})

app.use(express.static('public'))
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at https://localhost:' + port);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go into your **setting/preferences** and under **Request/Response** uncheck **Validate certificates**
[image: Uncheck Validate Certificates]

Comment: Not validating certificates removes all benefits of using HTTPS, at which point you might as well use plain HTTP.

Comment: For testing purposes you can disable, but Patrick is correct you lose all security benefits.  An acceptable answer should include how to fix the issue.

Comment: This appears to be a known bug in Insomnia that, as of June 2023, is still not fixed:
https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/2255

Answer (score 0):

My problem was only solved after creating a certificate file with the entire chain of information (SERVER CERT + ROOT CERT + INTERMEDIATE CERT). The screenshot below is from Step 1 of "[How to Install SSL Certificate on NGINX](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ssl-certificate-nginx#ftoc-heading-2)."

[image: screenshot of diagram]